# How to release fonts after generating pdf using iText7

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, itext7

I use iText 7.1.4.
In my program I can add/remove the fonts and using them in my pdf document.
I have a problem with remove operation. When I generate a pdf document and use some font of the list, then after that I can't delete this font! The font is still in use!
I wrote a small snippet code for example:

```
public void Generate()
{
    var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(@"E:\Test.PDF");
    var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);

    var document = new Document(pdfDocument);

    document.Add(
        new Paragraph("This test uses a Roboto Bold font")
        .SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(@"E:\Fonts\Roboto-Bold.ttf", "Cp1251", true))
        .SetFontSize(20));

    document.Close();
    pdfDocument.Close();
    pdfWriter.Close();
    pdfWriter.Dispose();
}
```

After executing this method, I can't delete the `E:\Fonts\Roboto-Bold.ttf` font. I can do that only if reboot my program.

How can I resolve this problem?

**UPDATED:**
The `PdfFont` type is not implement `IDisposable`, so it has't `Dispose()` method.

Comment: That's no very clear what do you want to do. do you want to remove some fonts from the resultant document?

Comment: @Uladzimir Asipchuk, The font file itself, which is on the disk, becomes blocked, after using it when generating pdf document. It doesn't want to unlock until i close the program

Comment: and so, who can help me?